# The named parameter 'icon' isn't defined. Try defining a named parameter with the name 'icon'

Tags: flutter, flutter-gridview

[Grid view with flutter icons with 2 columns and Each Images Text under the image aligned bottom center with 300 by 300 pixel dimensions or icon  size 98 or 85](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXRK7.jpg)My code is as below`import

```
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Digital Directory"),),
  body: Center(
      child: GridView.count(
        primary: false,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
        mainAxisSpacing: 10,
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            color: Colors.cyan[100],
             child: GestureDetector
          (
          onTap:(){

            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context)=>MobileAccessoriesPage(),
            ),
            );
          },

    child: Center (child:Text ('Mobiles'),icon:Icons.mobile_screen_share),

         ),
  ),
```

I am building grid view Application with flutter flat icons and I want to navigate when clicked on Flat Icons to another screens (i.e .dart page/screen)`

Comment: `Center` doesn't have an `icon` property. Please add a picture of what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the Child Of Center with the code below:

```
Center(
   child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                   children: [
                              Text(
                                'Mobiles',
                              ),
                              Icon(Icons.mobile_screen_share),
                            ],
                          ),
                         )
```

---

This would make the text 'mobiles' and the Icon to appear side by side. If you are not happy with the alignment change the `mainAxisAlignment` and the `crossAxisAlignment`

Comment: vThank You now the click event  is working fine and image is  showing. Please guide me How to increase the size of the icon and show the  Text under the image Bottom center aligned properly.

Comment: Change the icon size by specifying it in the `Icon(Icons.mobile_screen_share, size:50.0)` . I did not get the text under the image part it would be better if you could elaborate more.

Comment: I want the Title Text to be aligned to the bottomcenter i.e under each image to the center aligned properly

Comment: This would make the text 'mobiles' and the Icon to appear side by side. If you are not happy with the alignment change the mainAxisAlignment and the crossAxisAlignment.   Yes I am not Happy I want the Text Alignment to be aligned to the bottom center . please gudie me on it

Comment: I would suggest you look into `Columns`, `Row` and `Stack` widgets.

Comment: OK it would be  better if you help me with inserting cards and Text alignment etc.